# How do I connect the end of the extrusion back to the surface a second time?

Tags: modeling, faces

In the following the OP may be using the word [natural] where other people may understand the word [connected] as a single surface with a smooth contour.

[image][image]

I'm not sure how to fix this. The turn looks unnatural- even after I render. I'm not sure how/if I can comment images so I'm editing post to add them. Second image is render. Notice the bottom of handle connecting to mug looks natural while top looks unnatural.[image]

[image: This image is from front view]

Comment: To add: I don't think my parts are properly merged? I'll add an image to the post.

Comment: Is my first image not edit mode?

Comment: Please show you model in Edit Mode so all the vertices and edges are easier to see. Highlight the part of the image thats meets your needs and the part that does not.  So yes I was incomplete in my specification. You can use words such a good or bad with arrows or ... ☺or☹

Comment: Could you illustrate/describe what you feel would be natural, in this context? For example, would this be a 'natural' handle on a coffee mug, or a 'natural' branch on a tree?

Comment: So I am beginning to believe your question is ..... how can I attach both ends of my handle to the body of the teapot?

Comment: Kind of. I made the handle via extrusion from the mug but for whatever reason the top part of the handle doesn't appear to naturally combine with the body of the mug. I'm very brand new to this program, just started playing with it this morning so I am very unfamiliar with terms and what-not.

Comment: Yes ... connected as single surface may be the terminology you want.

Comment: Can you add your blend file to your question so that we can look at it?

Grab the URL of the question

Go to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Select the blend file

Add the url of the question

Grab the url that results

Go back to the question and edit it

Add the new url to the bottom of the post

Comment: I would actually like to see you expain what you want by editing the question.  File not needed.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Bridge edge loops to make the mug one connected surface.**

Use the Bridge operator to connect the open edge to a created hole in the mug

Use bevel operator to control the contour of handle to mug connection.

[image]

The bridge operator about to be executed. Note the hole at top is selected. The open circular edge of the handle is selected. Two holes aligned. Image above.  Please click on the image to see it larger in a separate web page.

---

[image]

The bridge operator finished. Surfaces are connected and ready for smoothing.  Image above

- Create a second hole in the destination area.  The vertex count of the hole should match the extruded vertex count.
- Use Mesh Loop Tools to change the hole into a circle, this is a time saver. Fine points not discussed here.
- Use Bridge edge loops to make the connection
- This whole operation could take 88 seconds for someone experienced.  If you take 8 minutes that is wonderful.

[image]

The Mug with Subdivision Surface Modifier and Smooth Shading.  No artistry intended.  You can do a better job.  Please improve and experiment.

There are often many way to do similar things in Blender.  You can experiment with extruding from two holes on the mug and having them meet in the middle with Bridge Edge Loops. Or something similar.  This technique follows.

[image]

Mug with two extrusions that meet in the middle of the handle.  In the top 3D View is the edit mode before bridge edge loops and finished version. In the bottom 3D view is showing the extrusion which uses the [Bevel] operator. This can be controlled by you for particular contours at the extrusion.  Handle formed with the Spin operator with a positive angle of 89 degrees and negative angle of 89 degrees.

Bridge edge loops is a time saver.  The other time wasting method is to connect each face separately by selecting the 4 vertices and creating a face with

<kbd>F</kbd>

Merge is also available.

There is also a way to get very convincing placement of vertices and lighting information using  two different meshes.  That can wait for another day.

---

Comment: I do have that modifier and even with smooth shading it looks the same